# Magento 2 : Customer Edit Shows Double Links After Upgrade

Tags: magento2, admin, customer, magento-upgrade, edit

After upgrade my magento2 from Magento 2.1.7 to latest version Magento 2.3.5, when I go to admin customer edit page that shows all links double.

Does anyone have idea how i can solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Kindly confirm that, there is not any third party extension which overide that thnigs?

Comment: yes i alredy try by disable all third party extensions than also get same issue